# How to set primary key type to UUID via Sequelize CLI

Tags: sequelize.js, sequelize-cli

I'm creating a DB model via [Sequelize CLI](https://github.com/sequelize/cli) with this command:

```sh
sequelize model:create --name User --attributes "firstname:string, lastname:string"
```

This creates the corresponding migration script:

```js
'use strict';
module.exports = {
  up: function(queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    return queryInterface.createTable('Users', {
      id: {
        allowNull: false,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true,
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER
      },
      firstname: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
      },
      lastname: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
      },
      createdAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE
      },
      updatedAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE
      }
    });
  },
  down: function(queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    return queryInterface.dropTable('Users');
  }
};
```

As shown, the primary key is set to `integer`.

Is there a way to default the CLI to use `UUID` instead?

Answer (score 64):

You can simple use the type UUIDV4 that comes with Sequelize.
Here is more details :
[UUIDV4](https://khalilstemmler.com/articles/auto-increment-or-uuid/)

For example making this definition:

```
id: {
  type: Sequelize.UUID,
  defaultValue: Sequelize.UUIDV4,
  allowNull: false,
  primaryKey: true
}
```

This is not using the Sequelize CLI but you can use that native UUIDV4 by manually changing that.

Comment: This answer is severely underrated.  It's way simpler/better than anything involving specifying beforeCreate hooks, migration scripts, etc.  This is the simplest answer, and it just plain works.  (I had been trying to use a set(value) function to set it.)  I believe you can make this CLI, maybe.  I think you can set certain properties when they're simple like that.

Comment: This answer worked for me.

if you are using TypeScript and `import { DataTypes } from "sequelize"` the usage is ```id: {
  type: DataTypes.UUID,
  defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4,
  allowNull: false,
  primaryKey: true,
}```

Comment: Depending on what version of sequelize you are using, and if you are using postgres this might not work. If you are using a later version of sequelize with postgres I recommend using the `uuid-ossp` extension

Answer (score 24):

You'd have to edit the generated file manually, changing `Sequelize.INTEGER` to `Sequelize.UUID`, then remove the `autoIncrement: true`.

`npm install uuid`

So your model would look like this:

```
const uuid = require('uuid/v4'); // ES5

'use strict';

module.exports = {
  up: function(queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    return queryInterface.createTable('Users', {
      id: {
        allowNull: false,
        primaryKey: true,
        type: Sequelize.UUID
      },
      /* Other model properties */
    });
  },
  down: function(queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    return queryInterface.dropTable('Users');
  }
};
```

Update your `beforeCreate` hook as follows:

```
const uuid = require('uuid/v4');

export default (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const User = sequelize.define('User', {
    id: {
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true,
      type: Sequelize.UUID
    },
    ...
  }, {});

  User.beforeCreate(user => user.id = uuid());

  return User;
};
```

> This assumes you are using Sequelize v4.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for MySQL. On insert I get: "Field 'id' doesn't have a default value"

Comment: You could use an npm package for generating UUID. `npm install uuid` or `npm install uuidv4`   

ES5
`const uuidv4 = require('uuid/v4');` or `const uuid = require('uuidv4')`   
`uuidv4();` or `uuid()`   

ES6
`import uuid from 'uuid/v4';`   
uuid()

On doing that replace the `defaultValue` property's value with a call to the required/imported `uuid`.
Doing this will allow auto generation of UUIDs on every save.

Comment: Just a tip. I feel like I'm having some success with Bookshelfjs and Knex, something else that bothers me about Sequelize is the difficulty of using unix timestamps for created/updated.

Comment: Does this work as expected? I tried this and it added the UUID correctly in the first attempt. On adding a second record, I got an error saying that the UUID already exists. So, I think that the `uuid()` line runs only once and gets set as the same for all records

Comment: @NikhilBaliga can you try it with the bottom part of the answer?

Comment: returning `() => uuid()` to defaultValue solves my problem in mysql db.

Comment: `defaultValue: Sequelize.UUIDV4` solved my problem with repeated uuid.

Answer (score 15):

The last answer will not work because the `uuid()` function will set a unique default value for all users in your database. Since they are a primaryKey, you will be able to persist only one user in the database, then everyone will receive the same uuid value and, of course, will not be persisted.

So... You have to:

1. In your migration file, remove `autoIncrement: true,` and change the type of your id from `type: Sequelize.INTEGER` to `type: Sequelize.UUID`
2. Install the uuid generator function from `npm i uuid --save`
3. In your generated User Model, change the `beforeCreate` function to generate a new uuid before insert it in the database, like this:

   ```
   const uuid = require('uuid/v4');
   /*...*/
   module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
     const User = sequelize.define('User', {
       /* Your User Model Here */
     }, {});
     User.beforeCreate((user, _ ) => {
       return user.id = uuid();
     });
     return User;
   };
   ```
4. Apply the changes of your migration by doing: `sequelize db:migrate:undo` follow by `sequelize db:migrate`
5. Test it.

Answer (score 11):

You can modify your migration script with this script

```
'use strict';
module.exports = {
  up: function(queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    return queryInterface.createTable('Users', {
      id: {
        primaryKey: true,
        type: Sequelize.UUID,
        defaultValue: Sequelize.literal('uuid_generate_v4()')
      },
      firstname: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
      },
      lastname: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
      },
      createdAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE
      },
      updatedAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE
      }
    });
  },
  down: function(queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    return queryInterface.dropTable('Users');
  }
};
```

It works for me.

Comment: That will work if you db ever execute this sql command: CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS "uuid-ossp"; That is if you use Postgresql.

Comment: Why would your UUID auto increment?

Comment: I've just edited, we don't need that line of code bro. And it still works. And make sure  CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS "uuid-ossp" is executed first like what @LEMUELADANE wrote.

Answer (score 8):

- No auto increment. UUID are randomly generated.
- Ensure you use `DataType.UUID` and default value to `UUIDV4`

No Auto increment. UUID are generated

```
export const User = db.define('user',
    {
        id: {
            type: DataTypes.UUID,
            defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4,
            primaryKey: true,
        },
```

Comment: Is it possible to get a shorter uid? Like 5-6 chars. UUIDV4 is rather excessive.

Answer (score 6):

If you need to make Postgres generate UUID on the insert as a default value,
this approach `defaultValue: Sequelize.UUIDV4` would not work. Anyway, Sequelize generates NULL value.

Instead, `Sequelize.literal('uuid_generate_v4()')` must be used.
That shall produce query `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "table" ("id" UUID NOT NULL DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4())`.

```
id: {
    allowNull: false,
    primaryKey: true,
    type: Sequelize.DataTypes.UUID,

    defaultValue: Sequelize.literal('uuid_generate_v4()'),
},
```

Comment: uuid_generate_v4() won't work of the box on Postgres, an extension is required.

Answer (score 6):

Any of the solutions mentioned above did not work for me. But was much helpful to arrive on my own resolution of the problem.

I'm using ES6+ syntax and solved this way:

PS: Sequelize on v5.x

**Migration**

```js
'use strict';

module.exports = {
  up: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.createTable('users', {
      id: {
        type: Sequelize.UUID,
        primaryKey: true,
        allowNull: false,
        defaultValue: Sequelize.UUIDV4,
      },
      name: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
      },
      created_at: {
        type: Sequelize.DATE,
        allowNull: false,
      },
      updated_at: {
        type: Sequelize.DATE,
        allowNull: false,
      }
    });
  },

  down: (queryInterface) => {
    return queryInterface.dropTable('users');
  }
}
```

**Model**

```js
import { uuid } from 'uuidv4';
import Sequelize, { Model } from 'sequelize';

class User extends Model {
  static init(sequelize) {
    super.init(
      {
        name: Sequelize.STRING,
      },
      {
        sequelize,
      }
    );

    this.addHook('beforeSave', async (user) => {
      return user.id = uuid();
    });

    return this;
  }
}

export default Users;
```

**Controller**

```js
import User from '../models/User';

class UserController {
  async store(request, response) {
    const { user } = request.body;

    const { id, name } = await User.create(users);

    return response.json({
      id,
      message: `User ${name} was register successful`,
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

I tried many options, everything turned out to be very simple. Try like this

Model:

```js
import { Model, DataTypes } from 'sequelize';
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';

import sequelize from '..';

class User extends Model {}

User.init(
  {
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.UUID,
      primaryKey: true,
      allowNull: false,
      defaultValue: () => uuidv4(),
    }
  },
  {
    sequelize,
    tableName: 'user',
    timestamps: false,
  },
);

export default User;
```

Migration:

```js
    const { v4: uuidv4 } = require('uuid');

module.exports = {
  up: async (queryInterface, DataTypes) => {
    await queryInterface.createTable('user', {
      id: {
        type: DataTypes.UUID,
        primaryKey: true,
        allowNull: false,
        defaultValue: uuidv4(),
      }
    });
  },

  down: async queryInterface => {
    await queryInterface.dropTable('user');
  },
};
```

Answer (score 2):

```
id: {
  type: Sequelize.UUID,
  defaultValue: Sequelize.UUIDV4,
  allowNull: false,
  primaryKey: true
}
```

The [answer from @Ismael Terreno](/a/58884380) is true; however, there is a bug that I'm not experienced enough to explain: if your model contains that format while using the examples provided from sequelize it will NOT work. Even so, you don't need to import UUID outside of sequelize; you can still take advantage of sequelize providing it, but you have to require it in for some reason like so:

```
"use strict";
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const User = sequelize.define(
    "User",
    {
      id: {
        primaryKey: true,
        type: DataTypes.UUID,
        defaultValue: require("sequelize").UUIDV4
      },
    {}
  );
  User.associate = function(models) {
    //enter associations here
    });
  };
  return User;
};`
```

I tested that and it worked, but I only found this out because of a previous success I had early on where my set up looked like this for the model, where I required everything before defining the model:

```
const { Sequelize, DataTypes, Model } = require("sequelize");
const db = require("../../config/database");

const userModel = db.define("users", {
  id: {
    type: DataTypes.UUID,
    defaultValue: Sequelize.UUIDV4,
    primaryKey: true
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you @TobySpeight for pointing me to improve. I went ahead and edited my answer accordingly. I'm new to this but totally agree with the importance specificity.

Comment: defaultValue: require("sequelize").UUIDV4 this worked for me. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your package.json has updated uuid module

```
"uuid": "^8.2.0",
```

This was the problem in my case as it was `3.4.0` before and sequelize does not work with that.

```
accessSecret: {
      type: DataTypes.UUID,
      defaultValue: Sequelize.UUIDV4,
      allowNull: false,
      unique: true,
    },
```

This works just fine after the uuid package upgrade on MySQL

Don't forget to change your imports to

`const { v4: uuid } = require('uuid')`

Tested on `"sequelize": "^5.21.13"`

Answer (score 2):

For sequelize `v6.5.0` using Postgres specifying `defaultValue: Sequelize.UUIDV4` did not work. Instead I had to do this:

```
'use strict';

module.exports = {
  up: async (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {

      await queryInterface.sequelize.query('CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS "uuid-ossp";')
      await queryInterface.addColumn('MyTable', 'id', {
        type: Sequelize.UUID,
        defaultValue: Sequelize.literal('uuid_generate_v4()'),
        allowNull: false,
        primaryKey: true
      })

  },
  down: async (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {

  }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

simply and work for all databases

```
 const uuidv4 = require('uuid/v4');

   id: {
      type: DataTypes.UUID,
      unique: true,
      primaryKey: true,
      isUUID: 4,
      defaultValue: uuidv4()
    },
```

Comment: Right on target

Comment: This is a bad idea, it'll use the first-value returned by `uuidv4()` because we're not passing the function to Sequelize, but the return value (which is probably just one id)

Answer (score 0):

To set the default value in migration you will need to write like this

```
id: {
      primaryKey: true,
      allowNull: false,
      defaultValue: Sequelize.literal("gen_random_uuid()"),
      type: Sequelize.UUID,
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help.
Install **uuid-ossp** extension in postgres so that you would be able to run **uuid_generate_v4()** function.

```
'use strict';
/** @type {import('sequelize-cli').Migration} */
module.exports = {
  async up(queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    await queryInterface.sequelize.query('CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS "uuid-ossp"');

    await queryInterface.createTable('users', {
      user_id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true,
      },
      user_uuid: {
        type: Sequelize.UUID,
        defaultValue: Sequelize.literal('uuid_generate_v4()'),
        allowNull: false,
        unique: true
      },
      first_name: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING(50),
        allowNull: false
      },
      created_at: {
        type: Sequelize.DATE,
        allowNull: false,
        defaultValue: Sequelize.literal('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP')
      },
      updated_at: {
        type: Sequelize.DATE,
        allowNull: false,
      }
    });

    // INDEXES
    await queryInterface.addIndex('users', ['user_uuid']);
  },
  async down(queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    await queryInterface.dropTable('users');
  }
};
```