# Sequelize create return id: undefined

Tags: node.js, mariadb, sequelize.js

when i do a create like this

```
const user = User.create();
```

if i print user on console the ID it return undefined, the data was inserted on the database but the id return as undefined.

I am using sequelize v6 and mariadb

My User model:

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
const User = sequelize.define('User', {
    id: {
        type: DataTypes.UUID,
        primaryKey: true,
        defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4
      },
    email_id: {
        type: DataTypes.UUID,
        defaultValue: null
      },
    auth_id: {
        type: DataTypes.UUID,
        defaultValue: null
      }
}, {
  tableName: 'user'
});
User.associate = function(models) {
  User.hasOne(models.UserEmail, {foreignKey: 'email_id', as: 'email'}),
  User.hasOne(models.UserAuth, {foreignKey: 'auth_id', as: 'auth'})
};
return User;
};
```

This is the console.log result

```
User {
 dataValues: {
  id: undefined,
   updatedAt: 2021-11-10T11:37:08.793Z,
   createdAt: 2021-11-10T11:37:08.793Z
 },
 _previousDataValues: {
  id: undefined,
  createdAt: 2021-11-10T11:37:08.793Z,
  updatedAt: 2021-11-10T11:37:08.793Z
 },
 _changed: Set(0) {},
  _options: {
   isNewRecord: true,
    _schema: null,
    _schemaDelimiter: '',
    attributes: undefined,
    include: undefined,
    raw: undefined,
    silent: undefined
  },
  isNewRecord: false
}
```

Comment: did you checked with "user.dataValues.id" ??

Comment: @boolfalse i have update my question and i have add the console.log result, yes i have check the user.dataValues.id it shows undefined

Comment: pay attention for you migration.. check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58884380/7574023)